# Debugger extremely slow if breakpoint is present

Tags: unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am writing pytests for a module and want to debug my way through the tests.
To debug my debugger issue i created a simple test:

```
def test_something():
    pass
```

which takes 0.001 seconds to run in the terminal.
If i try to debug this test WITH A BREAKPOINT, using vscodes test explorer extension(Holger Benl) the same test takes 40-80 seconds to complete.
If there is NO BREAKPOINT, the test runs in 4 seconds with the debugger (hitting debug).

I cant figure out why this is. The time increase of the terminal to debug run without breakpoint is also huge, but some delay due to vscode running debug is exoected I guess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: don't need to use an extension to unit test Python stuff, it is build in VSC, read the doc page on Python testing

Comment: any suggestion on how to solve this though?

Comment: don't use Holger Benl extension, but use the build-in Test Explorer View

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to inform that the exact same behaviour is seen using the build-in testing extension. Any suggestions are still welcome as I cant seem to figure out the root cause of this...

Comment: I've just tied it on one of my Python workspaces. Running the few tests almost instantaneous. Setting a breakpoint and debugging a test, a few seconds to start the debugger. I use the build in Test Explorer. I have Python 3.8 from python.org, I use a venv virtual environment with pandas, matplotlib,...